# How to add a date attribute to multiple expressions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a script and I have a problem with one thing.
It works smoothly:

```
klocek[i-1].id = i;
```

But I have a problem with that, I know that I probably do some stupid mistake but I have no ideas anymore.

```
klocek[i-1].setAttribute('data-poo', i);
```

Thanks for help.

Error: `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined`

> [image]

```
  for (var i = 1; i <= LICZBA_KLOCKOW; i++) {
     klocek[i-1].id = i;
     var rzad =  Math.floor(i / 5);
     klocek[i].setAttribute('data-poo', i);
  }
```

Comment: How is `knocek` defined?

Comment: var klocek = document.querySelectorAll(".klocek");

Comment: And do you have a loop that might be relevant to your question?  I.e. where does `i` come from.

Comment: Yes, of course i have loop for, and this work well with klocek[i-1].id = i;

Comment: Does this work? klocek[i-1].attr('data-poo', i);

Comment: Not really, Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined.

Comment: Have you got any elements with class `klocek` in your document? What is `klocek.length`?

Comment: Can you post the code for your loop?  I suspect that might be where the issue is.  I used your code you did provide and made a working example.

Comment: klocek.length = 20

Comment: Can you show us the whole loop?

Comment: Okay, i add code in pic right now.

Comment: It would have been better for you to add the code as text.

Comment: I wanted to do this, but unfortunately there was a formatting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue with your loop running out of bounds.  I would get rid of `LICZBA_KLOCKOW` altogether and replace it with `klocek.length`.

Here is a working example that may help:

```js
var klocek = document.querySelectorAll(".klocek");
for (var i = 0; i < klocek.length; i++) {
  klocek[i].id = i;
  klocek[i].setAttribute("data-poo", i)
}
```

```html
<div class="klocek">
klocek 1
</div>
<div class="klocek">
klocek 2
</div>
<div class="klocek">
klocek 3
</div>
<div class="klocek">
klocek 4
</div>
```

Comment: but if `klocek[i-1]` is `undefined` how he would be able to set `id` on it?

Comment: The problem was that after the for loop I did not open the {

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you don't have 20 elements of that class. You have fewer, but because your loop goes to 20, it's trying to find the nth element which isn't there.

Really your loop should look like this so that you're only looping through the actual elements in the nodelist:

```
for (var i = 0; i < klocek.length; i++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why i don't use naked loops anymore. I would suggest you to use `forEach` instead. But since `document.querySelectorAll` returns DOM elements collection and doesn't have this function you have to call it "from" array:

```
[].forEach.call(klocek, function (item, i) {
    item.id = i + 1;
    item.setAttribute("data-poo", i + 1);
});
```